# How to remove the panel at the right side of the ubuntu screen?

Tags: 11.04, panel, screen

When on the system, this gray bar takes up part of the right side and does not go away, despite changing backgrounds and appearance of menus. If the user is switched, the gray bar does not appear on the other user's account. Is there a way that I can remove this bar? 
[image]

Comment: Does anything happen if you RIGHT click on the bar?

Answer (score 3):

The bar is a Panel, you right-click on it and choose 'Delete this panel' to remove it.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much, my mouse was spoiled so I didn't notice this issue.